# How to align an asset image responsive at bottom center in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

here is the UI that I'm trying to build

[image]

but this is the output

[image]

I tried alignment also ,  but that also didn't working

but when setting a fixed height this is working fine

[image]

but I can't fill this using the fit parameter,

here is the code

```
Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: kDarkTheme,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const SizedBox(height: 10),
              Row(
                  //code for top button
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 150),
              Stack(
                children: [
                  Center(
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: radiusSize + 5,
                      backgroundColor: kDarkCounterColor,
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundColor: kDarkTheme,
                        radius: radiusSize,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Center(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 35),
                      child: Text(
                        '39',
                        style: GoogleFonts.italiana(
                            fontSize: 120, color: kDarkCounterColor),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 15),
              const Text(
                'Tap To Count',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Helvatica',
                  color: Color(0xff656158),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    child: SvgPicture.asset(
                  kDarkThemeImage,
                )),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ))
```

this is the code
then the first error appears again. how could I fix this?

Comment: hi, Mishalhaneef. Could you please post the relevant part of your code, maybe the general structure of columns/rows/widgets you are using that are causing the issue? best regaards

Comment: @George hey George, i added the code, please check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `Expanded` widget on a column that doesn't have a set size. Try adding MainAxisSize attribute to your column, like this:

```
Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,  // Add this like
    children: [
       ...
```

This will make your column fit the whole available size on the previous widget (a scaffold for the whole screen). Then the expanded widget will fill the remaining space not used by the other widgets inside the column.

Comment: its not working, it's just showing a blank screen, I think every widget is expanding to out of the screen or something, I don't get that.     can you check the full code please  https://github.com/Mishalhaneef/counter_app